# Bulk change Year only in worpdress posts

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I am trying to update ONLY the year for the publish date for all the posts AND pages on a wordpress sites.

By mistake i did a find and replace with a plugin and replaced 2018 with 2019. As a result of that, lots of posts are showing up as "Scheduled" as their publish date was changed to 2019. I actually only wanted to change the 2018 year in the posts/pages titles, not the publish dates.

I am wondering if this will work but I am concern it might damage the whole website. This is some code I found online:

```
UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_date = REPLACE(post_date, '2019-‘, '2018-')
WHERE post_date LIKE '%2018-%'
```

I am not sure if this is the correct code to run in phpmyadmin. I have backed up the website before doing any changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use date specific function rather than string based.

```
UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_date = post_date + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
WHERE YEAR(post_date) = 2018;
```

Comment: Still asking, whether you want to update titles or post date?

Comment: thanks a lot for the help!

as of now, i only wanted to update the post date.

but for the future, it'd be awesome if i can replace the "2018" text in the titles and meta titles with "2019", but do not change the post date at all. Any suggestions how i could do that as well?

Comment: Based on schema, we can check how we can do that.

Comment: If this solves your problem, do accept and vote up the answer :)

Comment: out of curiosity, will this function in phpmyadmin ALSO change the published date in sitemap.xml file? or do i have to manually change it in the sitemap.xml file? (i am using either Yoast or All in One SEO wordpress plugins to generate the xml sitemaps)

Comment: Just wanted to followup on this: the function worked beautifully and it fixed my issue. in terms of the xml sitemap, i can see i got the last updated on in the xml sitemap. i think this is good so far, all is good, thanks once again!